# What are the key lessons that Poker teaches that can be applied to successful speculation?

Tags: learning, casino, soft-question

There are several well-known successful hedge fund managers who love Poker. David Einhorn, Jim Chanos are just a few examples. On a personal level, I hear of successful investors who are fond of Poker. I am hazarding a guess that Poker is a factor in the success of these speculators.

What are the key lessons that Poker teaches that can be applied to successful speculation?

Comment: Aaron Brown has written about it, for instance, [here](https://www.quora.com/Would-playing-poker-help-you-understand-finance/answer/Aaron-Brown-165) and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-lifeskills-one-can-learn-from-regularly-playing-poker/answer/Aaron-Brown-165).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is neccessary to know is the following:

- Did he start to play poker after he was a successful hedge fund manager?

There are some people who get successful and this time by successful I mean having money and after they got the money, they started playing poker. And there are of course guys who are good in poker and love it an do their normal job as for example hedge fund manager.
Daniel Einhorn was ranked top 20 in 2006 WSOP and he played the one million dollar buy in tournament in 2011 or 2012 and he was placed as 3rd. Do not missunderstand me, but there were 22 people participating and I don't think that all these guys won the money from poker. What I want to say is, that this tournament was more for rich guys instead of poker players. But that's just my thinking, I couldn't find a list of players involved.

What I want to point out is that I guess Daniel started to play Poker after his success in his job. But anyway Poker will give  u real probabilities which you can always use for something else. Some people think that they are luckier than others or whatever, you will not have the same feeling after playing poker for ages. You will see that the numbers don'T care if you are rich or black or white or green with stripes. I think the more poker you play the less you try to gamble with things.